VS Code Docker dev container error at end of process
Setting up a Docker dev container in VS Code with a FrankenPHP service depending on a Memcached and a Postgres service, I get to the point of the Memcached and Postgres services up and running, and the main App service dumps with an error or two.
Docker log with the error sequence:
 ✔ Container newseeds_devcontainer-db-1     Running                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container newseeds_devcontainer-cache-1  Running                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container newseeds_devcontainer-app-1    Started                        0.0s 
[1292 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=com.docker.compose.project=newseeds_devcontainer --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=app
[1330 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 38bd8826df6d
[1442 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[1442 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 38bd8826df6d56722aa2b2b25d8f082630e1f7c2043e9c722135edd839838a7f
[1473 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh
[1474 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[1505 ms] Shell server terminated (code: 1, signal: null)
[1505 ms] Error response from daemon: container 38bd8826df6d56722aa2b2b25d8f082630e1f7c2043e9c722135edd839838a7f is not running
[1505 ms] Start: Run in container:  (command -v getent >/dev/null 2>&1 && getent passwd 'root' || grep -E '^root|^[^:]*:[^:]*:root:' /etc/passwd || true)
[1505 ms] Stdin closed!
[1505 ms] Error: An error occurred setting up the container.
[1505 ms]     at CtA (/Users/fpolli/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.354.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:409:3709)
[1505 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[1505 ms]     at async UtA (/Users/fpolli/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.354.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:3865)
[1505 ms]     at async $C (/Users/fpolli/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.354.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:481:4807)
[1505 ms]     at async QrA (/Users/fpolli/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.354.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:13255)
[1505 ms]     at async urA (/Users/fpolli/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.354.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:661:12996)
[1507 ms] Exit code 1

Below are the docker-compose file, the dockerfile for the app container, and the devcontainers.json:
docker-compose:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    entrypoint: php artisan octane:frankenphp --max-requests=1
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
    volumes:
      - storage://D/www/laravel-projects/newseeds/storage
    command: sleep infinity,
    networks:
      - storefront
      - backroom
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - data://D/PostgreSQL/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: theuser
      POSTGRES_DB: arandomname
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "very ultra secret"
    networks:
      - backroom
  cache:
    image: memcached:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    #volumes:
    networks:
      - backroom

networks:
  storefront:
  backroom:

volumes:
  data:
  storage:

Dockerfile:
FROM dunglas/frankenphp

RUN install-php-extensions pcntl

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["php", "artisan", "octane:frankenphp"]

devcontainer.json

  "name": "the name",
  "dockerComposeFile": "./docker-compose.yaml",
  "service": "app",
  "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
  "features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/node:1": {
      "nodeGypDependencies": true,
      "version": "lts",
      "nvmVersion": "latest"
    },
  },
    "forwardPorts": [
      5432
    ],
    //"remoteUser": "root",
    "customizations": {
      "vscode": {
        "extensions": [
          "onecentlin.laravel5-snippets"
        ]
      }
    }
  }

Note that I develop on a Windows 11 PC desktop and a MacBook, and on the PC the "remoteUser" line needs to be active in order for the devcontainer.json file to be read, and on the MacBook, it needs to be commented out. I wrote this on the MacBook, hence the commenting. The outcome is the same on both computers.
Thank you.

Were you able to solve this?

I don't think I was. I just went about things a different way.
